# Fixed point implication question

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ is continuous and $f''>0$. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to argue that if $f(x^*) = x^*$ and $f'(x^*) \geq 1$, then $f(x) > x$ for all $ x > x^*$.

My attempt: By the fundamental theorem, we know that
\begin{equation}{
f(x) - f(x^*) = \int_{x^*}^xf'(a)da\geq \int_{x^*}^x 1 da = x-x^*
}\end{equation}
Then since $f(x^*)=x^*$, we have $f(x) \geq x$. However, I don't think this works because we only know $f'(x^*) \geq 1$, not $f'(a)\geq 1$ for all $a \geq x^*$. Also, the inequality should be $>$ not $\geq$. I wonder if I could use the convexity of $f$ to show that $f'(a) \geq 1$ for all $a \geq x^*$, but I couldn't figure out how to do it, or  if I'm just way off track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem twice. We have, by the fundamental theorem
$$ f'(x) = f'(x^*) + \int_{x^*}^x f''(\xi)\, d\xi > f'(x^*) \ge 1, \quad x > x^* $$
So $f'(x) > 1$ for $x > x^*$. Now
$$ f(x) = f(x^*) + \int_{x^*}^x f'(\xi)\, d\xi > f(x^*) + (x-x^*) = x. $$